# Fuzzy Matching Emails on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, fuzzy-comparison

I would like to match names and emails that are spelled differently in various datasets on our BigQuery Data Warehouse.

I've done cursive research on Fuzzy Matching on BigQuery.

- [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546130/is-approximate-string-matching-fuzzy-string-searching-possible-with-bigquery) is 6 years old.
- I do not think I can use [metaphones](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/EXAMPLE---Double-Metaphone-Functions_132067469) as the majority of user names are transliterated from non-English names.
- I found [this exciting article series](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-journey-into-bigquery-fuzzy-matching-4-of-1-a-tribute-to-fuzzywuzzy-54ff73e91a1c) but it seems that this is way advanced and perhaps over the top for this modest use (reconciling user identities) and it also depends on non-SQL scripts.

So back to SO: how can I fuzzy match emails and or names? Here are fictive examples:

- *benjamin.mckinnen ~ benjamin.mackinnen*
- *muhammad.aktar ~ mohammad.akhtar*
- *georgerobert.martin ~ george.martin*
- *voravut.pisombhon ~ worawuth.pisombong*

Can Levenshtein Distance be calculate in pure SQL? Are there alternatives?